# Is there a way to custom Marshaling Protobuf in golang?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to custom marshal/unmarshal protobuf just like how encoding/json provides way to [custom marshal/unmarshal json](http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/) in golang?

Answer (score 2):

Update :

The [proto3](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3) go library (https://google.golang.org/protobuf/proto) does not support custom marshalling anymore.

---

Deprecated:

GoDoc mentions [Marshaler](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Marshaler) and [Unmarshaler](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Unmarshaler) interfaces.

```
type Marshaler interface {
    Marshal() ([]byte, error)
}

type Unmarshaler interface {
    Unmarshal([]byte) error
}
```

Comment: This method is deprecated