# How to "extend" a message with a new (timestamp) field?

Tags: protocol-buffers

A bit of background first:

A project I'm working on streams data from a source and to a destination. A single piece of data read from a source and sent downstream is called a record. A source can be an SQL database, a blob storage etc.

Under the hood, records are sent through gRPC and represented as Protocol Buffer 3 messages like below (simplified, full proto [here](https://github.com/ConduitIO/conduit-connector-protocol/blob/main/proto/opencdc/v1/opencdc.proto#L50)):

```
message Record {
  string id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Struct payload = 2;
}
```

A shortcoming we became aware of is that `payload` cannot contains timestamps ([supported values](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto#L62-L78)). Given that it's an often used type, making it possible to use it right away makes it easier for developers to work with the tool.

I saw a few options:

1. Custom marshallers
2. A special `google.protobuf.Struct` which describes a timestamp (e.g. `{"type": "timestamp", "value": "12345"}`)
3. Completely replace `google.protobuf.Struct` with a message of similar structure but with a timestamp.

It looks like custom marshallers are not possible (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56414869) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41606157)).

Encoding timestamps using special structs is possible, but I'm worried about performance. I would need to recursively go into `payload` to check all fields but also nested fields.

Completely replacing `google.protobuf.Struct` doesn't have that problem:

```
// Copied from google.protobuf.Struct
message MyStruct {
  map<string, MyValue> fields = 1;
}

// copied from google.protobuf.Value
message Value {
  // The kind of value.
  oneof kind {
    // Represents a null value.
    NullValue null_value = 1;
    // Represents a double value.
    double number_value = 2;
    // Represents a string value.
    string string_value = 3;
    // Represents a boolean value.
    bool bool_value = 4;
    // Represents a structured value.
    Struct struct_value = 5;
    // Represents a repeated `Value`.
    ListValue list_value = 6;
    // Represents a timestamp
    TimestampValue timestamp_value = 7

  }
}
```

This should be backwards compatible (clients using `google.protobuf.Struct` are still able to send it since the field tags are kept). However, it feels a like bit hacky.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WKT [`Struct`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#struct) is a way to represent JSON as a Protobuf message. Every possible (!?) JSON message can be represented by `Struct`. Adding a new message type (e.g. `Timestamp`) is redundant because it does not add to `Struct`'s ability to represent JSON. You don't explain your underlying purpose of `Struct` beyond wanting to represent timestamps. If you're using `Struct` to represent JSON, you could consider using RFC3339 strings for timestamp values. This is what the `Timestamp` language-specific packages do.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for your reply! I've added a bit more context about the background. Your question made me question my approach. The proto message is not the level where I should be handling this, but the domain model, if possible. I'll give it some more thoughts.

Comment: IIUC you want to transmit arbitrary structured content in `payload`. I think your comment is correct. Protobuf messages must adhere to a schema and you've options: (1) Use `Struct` aka JSON generally used with JSON (un)marshaller but not necessarily so; the content is structured but it is not self-describing; (2) Use `OneOf` this requires that you be able to statically define all the types; (3) Use `Any` (uncommon!?) this permits dynamically (!) defined types but every type must be defined; (4) use `string` or `bytes` (limited size) and not self-describing.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @DazWilkin! Can you elaborate (1) a bit more please?

Comment: There's not a lot more I can add. If your message payloads are JSON, the protobuf language SDKs provide mechanisms to (un)marshal the JSON as `Struct`. If the message payloads aren't JSON, you can still use `Struct` but you'll have to write methods to convert the content to `Struct` yourself.